# CV and cover letter in same file with own titles: Moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I'd like to add my cover letter with the title "Cover letter" after my CV part in `moderncv`. I use `classic` style and I tried to add `\title{Cover letter}` after the `\clearpage` and before `\makelettertitle` but it doesn't print it anything. Has someone solved this problem?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 


\moderncvstyle{classic}                           
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\title{Curriculum vitae}
\name{John}{Doe}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makecvtitle

\title{Cover letter}
\recipient{HR Departmnet}{Corporation\\123 Pleasant Lane\\12345 City, State} 
\date{\today} 
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,} 
\closing{Sincerely yours,}


\makelettertitle
\end{document}
```

I'd like to print "cover letter" title with same font/size as the curriculum vitae title on the cover letter portion of my application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update (`moderncv` v2.0)

With `moderncv` v2.0, the command to be patched is no more `\makelettertitle` but `\makeletterhead`, so the correct patch for this version is

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}
  {\recomputeletterlengths}
  {\recomputeletterlengths\titlestyle{\@title}\par\vspace{2cm}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
```

---

### Original answer (works with older versions of `moderncv`)

Add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makelettertitle}
  {\recomputeletterlengths}
  {\recomputeletterlengths\titlestyle{\@title}\par\vspace{2cm}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}


\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makelettertitle}
  {\recomputeletterlengths}
  {\recomputeletterlengths\titlestyle{\@title}\par\vspace{2cm}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\title{Curriculum vitae}
\name{John}{Doe}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makecvtitle

\clearpage

\title{Cover letter}
\recipient{HR Departmnet}{Corporation\\123 Pleasant Lane\\12345 City, State}
\date{\today}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Sincerely yours,}

\makelettertitle
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]